# Статус директора — правильно ли составлено предложение?

Tags: стилистика

> "Статус директора: какими правами он наделяет и какие обязанности возлагает?"

Все ли здесь правильно? Можно ли сказать, что статус наделяет правами?

> "Кроме перечисленных прав директор также принимает решения о награждении учеников".

Мне кажется, что здесь что-то не так.

Comment: Заголовок вопроса должен отражать его специфику. Одна тема должна содержать один вопрос.

Comment: @juki, странные ограничения у вас.

Comment: Я с такими ограничениями на этом сайте впервые встречаюсь. Неприятно.

Comment: Не обращайте внимания. juki - не модератор. Если какие-то вопросы, обращайтесь ко мне.

Comment: Ок, спасибо

Comment: >Не обращайте внимания. juki - не модератор.

Это бунт? Или то, что модератор отменяет распоряжения админа, здесь в порядке вещей?

Comment: А где список админов и модераторов можно полностью полице/зреть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По первому предложению. Статус, пожалуй, не наделяет правами и обязанностями, а предусматривает их. "Статус директора: какие права и обязанности он предусматривает." Хотя так всё равно не понятно кто на ком стоял. Лучше обойтись без местоимения. Например: "Статус директора: права и обязанности".

Второе предложение вообще кривое, лучше переделать. Например: "Вопрос о награждении учеников также находится в компетенции директора".

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд,этот вопрос относится не к стилистике,а к лексике. "Положение" не может ни наделять правами, ни возлагать обязанности. Чаще можно встретить в официально-деловом стиле "положение обязывает".

Answer (score 0):

Гм... по поводу второго, мне кажется, что лучше будет сказать (хотя это будет тавтология, конечно) "Кроме перечисленных прав директор также имеет право принимать решения..." То есть, речь все время должна идти о правах.

Answer (score 0):

В первом вопросе мне очень не нравится двоеточие. Я бы сказал, что *"статус директора"* — это именительный темы, и отделил бы точкой: *"Статус директора. Какими правами он наделяет и какие обязанности возлагает?"*

Во втором, я думаю, обособленное дополнение (*"кроме..."*) должно согласоваться со сказумым, то есть: *"Кроме перечисленных прав, директор также имеет право принимать решения о награждении учеников".*

Comment: "Имеет право принимать решения" - это вообще неоднозначная фраза по сути. То есть имеет право и не принимать решений?


Answer (score 0):

А мне первое предложение даже нравится, звучит смело, подошло бы в качестве заголовка к статье (но не годится для официально-делового, канцелярского стиля). Во втором "Кроме перечисленных прав" - явное излишество, без этой фразы можно легко обойтись.